# How can I implement exclusive toggling buttons with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make each different button to initiate a different function (graph) effect. I have 3 buttons, and they should all be exclusive such that, if button 1 is pressed, button 2 and 3 should be deactivated and its corresponding functions

If button 1 is pressed, function 1 should fire and 2 & 3 should not 
If button 2 is pressed, function 2 should fire and 1 & 3 should not
If button 3 is pressed, function 3 should fire and 1 & 2 should not

In this example, pressing button 1 should draw a graph with points of 14, 10, 11,  button 2 should draw 26, 31, 28, and button 3 should draw 52, 48, 38

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sctcmr1h/6/

**HTML**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button1" >Button 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button2">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button3">Button 3</button>

  <div id="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background: #124364;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#container{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #336699;
  color: white;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function button1() {
  var data = [{
    X: 14
  }, {
    X: 10
  }, {
    X: 11
  }];

  var processedData = [];
  Highcharts.each(data, function button1(d) {
    processedData.push(d.X);
  });

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
      data: processedData,
    }],

  });
});

$(function button2() {
  var data = [{
    X: 26
  }, {
    X: 31
  }, {
    X: 28
  }];

  var processedData = [];
  Highcharts.each(data, function button2(d) {
    processedData.push(d.X);
  });

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
      data: processedData,
    }],

  });
});

$(function button3() {
  var data = [{
    X: 52
  }, {
    X: 48
  }, {
    X: 38
  }];

  var processedData = [];
  Highcharts.each(data, function button3(d) {
    processedData.push(d.X);
  });

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
      data: processedData,
    }],

  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sctcmr1h/6/

The way I was thinking of writing was something along this line but I do not think this is an accurate way of making 3 buttons exclusive

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Button ID').click(function 1 2 or 3() {
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

  $('#container').hide();
} else {
  $('#container').show();
  function 1 2 or 3();
}
$(this).toggleClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons?

Comment: @Maulzal, the reason I tried to avoid the radio button is for the future. Later on, I will need some buttons to simultaneously fire functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have highcharts installed, but I can show you how I'd do the rest of it:

```
var data = [
    [{ X: 14 }, { X: 10 }, { X: 11 }],
    [{ X: 26 }, { X: 31 }, { X: 28 }],
    [{ X: 52 }, { X: 48 }, { X: 38 }],
  ],
  displyChart = function(i){
    var processedData = data[i].map(function(point){
       return point.X;
    });
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      series: [{
        data: processedData,
      }],
    });
  };
$('.btn-chart').click(function() {
  $('.btn').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  displyChart($(this).attr('data-chart'));
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/sctcmr1h/7/

I wasn't sure why you were hiding and showing "#container", so I left that off.

Oh, I also got rid of the ids in the buttons.  I usually try to remove id declarations where possible.  I added a "data-chart" attribute, and a more specific class:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-chart" data-chart="0">Details</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-chart" data-chart="1">Details</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-chart" data-chart="2">Details</button>

  <div id="container"></div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello William. One thing about this method is that, when one button is pressed, you cannot press other buttons until the pressed button is de-pressed. Is there a way to get around this? Such as , when you have one button pressed and when you press another button, it de-pressed the previously selected button ?

Comment: Oh - I did that on purpose.  I  thought you wanted to disable the other buttons because of this statement: "if button 1 is pressed, button 2 and 3 should be deactivated and its corresponding functions"  The disabled version is harder.  Also I used an index starting at 1 instead of 0 for the data.  I've fixed it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/sctcmr1h/7/